# UITableView's deleting animation does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

When I trying to delete a row in UITableview, the list move up 2 rows and the animation behavior is also strange, as you could see 2 "Water:11" cells appears(moves down)... How's that going on? I use swift with a Xcode version 9.4.1, and here is my delete code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
     let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "DELETE") { (action, actionIndexPath) in
         tableView.beginUpdates()
         tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
         Results.remove(at: indexPath.row)
         tableView.endUpdates()
     }
     return [deleteAction]
}
```

[a GIF that shows what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZkkr.gif)

Comment: Yeah it solves my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tableview didn't get row height properly this kind of issue occur. To fix that you just need to give estimated row height. Thanks